# Can I embed a webpage on another webpage while editing some the Content of embedded webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to embed a webpage inside another webpage while embedding that webpage I want to edit its contents a little bit.
to embed a webpage I am using this Script. I can edit content out of the object using this simple javascript .but I can't edit anything  Inside the object or the embedded webpage. Please help In any way u can. Solutions involving any kind of workaround will be appreciated

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('hello', 'another text');
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p id="myP">I am a paragraph.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p>hello</p>



  <object type="text/html" data="https://www.socialcommer.com/store/mykitchenmydish/1" style="width:100px; height:100px; ">
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the content is not on the same domain as the parent frame then this will not be possible, for very obvious security reasons.

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan just wanted to edit some content before displaying